# What is wrong with this chart?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have the following code to make the chart. But the graph display wrong.

Here is the code

```
Ext.onReady(function(){
Ext.define('FinancialRatio',{
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: ['year','revenue']
});

var FinancialRatioStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store',{
    model: 'FinancialRatio',
    autoLoad:true,
    proxy:{
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'http://localhost/FinancialRatio.php',
        reader:{
            type: 'xml',
            record: 'ratio'
        }
    }
});

var revenue = Ext.create('Ext.Window',{
    width: 400,
    height:300,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    hidden: false,
    maximizable: true,
    title: 'Revenue',
    layout: 'fit',
    items:{
        xtype: 'chart',
        style: 'background:#fff',
        store: FinancialRatioStore,
        animate: true,
        axes:[{
            title: 'Revenue',
            type: 'Numeric',
            position: 'left',
            fields: ['revenue']
        },{
            title: 'Year',
            type: 'Category',
            position: 'bottom',
            fields: ['year']

        }],
        series:[{
            type: 'line',
            xField: 'year',
            yField: 'revenue'

        }]
    }

});
```

And here is the result

[image]

But the actual data is as follow (I wrote the grid code to display this data)

[image]

Base on the data, the graph is displaying wrong. But I cant figure out where I did wrong. Could you please help me out?

Also, what is the differences between the "fields" in axes and the "xfield" and "yfield" in series?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing the issue is because you didn't set the field type in your model.  Try this:

```
Ext.define('FinancialRatio',{
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: ['year', //when no type specified, it defaults to 'string'
    {
       name: 'revenue',
       type: 'int'
    }]
});
```

An axis can contain many fields so that you can plot multiple series against them.  For example, if you wanted to plot revenue and profit, you would want to have axis fields `['revenue', 'profit']` and you would define multiple series:

```
series: [{
   type: 'line',
   xField: 'year',
   yField: 'revenue'
}, {
   type: 'line',
   xField: 'year',
   yField: 'profit'
}]
```

Comment: Great. I didn't believe I messed at this model again. Thank you. It worked great now. Can you tell me the differences between the "fields" in axes and the "xfield" and "yfield" in series? Thanks

Comment: Yes, but would it be redundant? because you already define the data flow in the series already. Why would it needed to do it again on the axis?

Comment: It's so you can have multiple axes.  For example, if `profit` was measured in thousands of dollars, and `revenue` was measured in tens of thousands of dollars, you could have two separate y-axes (one for each field).